# Настройка Git Pages

Tags: github, github-pages

У меня в репозитории index.html находится в папке build, git Hub Pages пытается найти файл в корневой папке, и чтобы файл нашелся приходится дописать /build. Подскажите как настроить так, чтобы git Pages открывался сразу в папке build? https://github.com/GreenTea-so/Tema4_2  вот ссылка на репозиторий, а вот на Pages https://greentea-so.github.io/Tema4_2/build/

Comment: Никак по сути. Можно настроить ci/cd, чтобы билд добавлялся в отдельную ветку в корень (допустим, в ветку gh-pages), и настроить github pages, чтобы содержимое бралось из нее.

Comment: P.S., а, ну еще можно в папку docs билдить вместо build, тогда можно настроить: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBguA.png

Comment: Вот да, я сейчас работаю с Travis CI, я вас правильно понял, я должен файлы из build копировать в корень директории?

Comment: Как можно с помощью Travis CI создать ветку и туда засунуть файлы из build?

Comment: Нет, я имею в виду, что можно добавить полностью отдельную пустую ветку, в которую ci/cd будет деплоить сгенерированные файлы (традиционно для github pages используют ветку gh-pages), и в нее деплоить. По деплою с travis на github pages вот такую инструкцию нашел: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/pages/

Comment: спасибо тебе большое, все получилось